# Filter on tag. Check if tag is in database string. Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am looking for a query to check if my $tag-variable (a string) is part of a string that I put in a database through an input field. The user can add an article en give tags to it by separating it with a comma. This all work and the user can go to the article/{tag} url, but I am not able to show all the articles with that specific tag.

So what do I need to do? I need to check if the $tag is part of a string that's in the database (in the "tags" column). I tried it and this is my controller. I don't really know if the contains()-function works.

here is my controller-code:

```
     public function getTag($tag)
{

    $articles = Article::where('tags',contains('tags', $tag))->get();


    return view("article.tagFilter")->with('articles',$articles);
}
```

Comment: `I don't really know if the contains()-function works`. You didn't try? What happened?

Comment: I tried it and I do not see the articles I needed to see on de articles/{tag} page. I think because the query is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution here is :

```
    $articles = Article::where('tags', 'LIKE', '%'.$tag.'%')->get();
```

Thanks to lamzozo!

Comment: Don't forget to mark lamzozo's answer as the right one if that's the answer that helped you solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you have a `tags` varchar column in articles table (comma separated string in it), and you want to search for this.

```
$articles = Article::where('tags', 'LIKE', "%$tag%")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, their is just one thing you need to change here. You need to put the $tag outside the quotes.

            $articles = Article::where('tags', 'LIKE', '%'.$tag.'%')->get();

Comment: Hoops, single quotes, with double you don't need to join strings. Updated answer.